# Youtube mockup-alike dummy placeholder for text and images during ajax-call loading

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, frontend

Various Websites and apps like Youtube show some mockup-alike dummy placeholder for text and images during ajax-calls are loading the actual content. Like grey boxes instead of lines of text. I am looking for best practices and showcases.
So this is actually less of a specific coding-issue. I just would be glad about some hints or keywords that could help.
Or is this something everyone builds from scratch in his own humble way?
I hope this is not the wrong place for a relatively unspecific question like this...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: search for "content loading placeholder" there are a few tutorials on how to achieve this

Comment: The term you'll see most often for these is "skeleton screens." Googling around for that should get you headed in the right direction. However, this probably doesn't fit here as a question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @creme and @ajm!

"skeleton screens" or "content loading placeholder" is exactly what I meant.